# How do you bring to top of function to repeat the function over and over?

Tags: javascript, repeat

I have this function that can handle everything I need for my program, but I just need a way to add to the bottom something that can make the function repeat itself.

```
function main(){
   var scoreCounter= 0
   var random= Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
   currentTarget= targets[random]
   currentTarget.style.display= "block"
   currentTarget.addEventListener("click", function(){
      currentTarget.style.display= "none"
      scoreCounter+=1
      aimHero.innerHTML= "Score: " + scoreCounter
})
}
```

Comment: Just call main() at last line of your function, that will make it to call itself again, but you also need to add conition to stop it (make return), otherwise it will be infinity loop an dyout page will freeze.

Comment: You are going to have to unbind events.

Answer (score 1):

So in The click call the code to do it again. You are going to have to unbind the event listener so you are not adding multiple clicks to elements when they appear for the second time.

```js
function main() {
  var scoreCounter = 0;
  var targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
  var aimHero = document.querySelector('#aimHero');
  function nextTarget() {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * targets.length));
    var currentTarget = targets[random];
    currentTarget.style.display = "block";

    function performClick() {
      currentTarget.style.display = "none";
      scoreCounter += 1;
      aimHero.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreCounter;
      // remove target
      currentTarget.removeEventListener("click", performClick);
      // do it again
      nextTarget();
    }
    currentTarget.addEventListener("click", performClick);
  }
  nextTarget();
}

main();
```

```css
div {
min-height: 50px;
}
.target {
  display:none;
  background-color:red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="aimHero"></div>
<div><div class="target">1</div></div>
<div><div class="target">2</div></div>
<div><div class="target">3</div></div>
<div><div class="target">4</div></div>
<div><div class="target">5</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE delegate

This is so much simpler than removing and adding event handlers

```js
let scoreCounter = 0;
const aimHero = document.querySelector('#aimHero');
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const targets = container.querySelectorAll(".target");
const len = targets.length;
targets.forEach(tgt => tgt.hidden = true)
container.hidden = false;
const nextTarget = () => {
  const random = Math.floor((Math.random() * len));
  var currentTarget = targets[random];
  currentTarget.hidden = false;
}

const performClick = e => {
  e.target.closest("div").hidden = true;
  scoreCounter += 1;
  aimHero.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreCounter;
  nextTarget();
}
container.addEventListener("click", performClick);

nextTarget();
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.target {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="aimHero"></div>
<div id="container" hidden>
  <div><div class="target">1</div></div>
  <div><div class="target">2</div></div>
  <div><div class="target">3</div></div>
  <div><div class="target">4</div></div>
  <div><div class="target">5</div></div>
</div>
```